# Calling Controller Function within a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I have am new to Angular and messing around with Controllers. I created this simple controller function:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
            this.product = gem;
});

    var gem = {
        name: "Dodecahedron",
        price: 2.95,
        description: '...'
        };    


})();
```

When I call this controller under my index.html, it works perfectly. Here is my index.html:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src = "angular.min.js"></script> <!--ANGULAR SOURCE-->
<script src = "app.js"></script> <!--APP SOURCE-->
<link rel = "stylesheet" href  = "bootstrap.css" type = "text/css"> <!--BOOTSTRAP-->

</head>

<body ng-app = "store">
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2> {{store.product.price}} </h2>
    <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

My code is working find and as expected. However, I don't get what the purpose of the last set of parentheses is in my controller function because once I take it out, my controller no longer works. It seems unnecessary, but for some reason my controller won't work without it. Could someone provide me with why this isn't working?

thanks!

Comment: Which parentheses exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Angular is somewhat an advanced js framework. Hence to master it, one needs knowledge of js itself. I'd recommend you to read through this splendid book series first. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Answer (score 2):

The whole

```
(function(){


})()
```

surrounding code is called a "self invoking function". Thus, omitting () just define a function and never calls it, so your angular app doesn't get its "store" module configured.

Its purpose here, is to create a scope so that the variable "app" and any other variable do not leak into the global (window) context.

If you use a module bundler like webpack which already add a local function context, then this become redundant. I assume it's useful for you because you have a script tag for every angular file in your app.